# Django - 403 error while accessing static files in ec2 ubuntu server with nginx

Tags: django, nginx, http-status-code-403, django-staticfiles, ubuntu-22.04

I have used nginx default port 80. Deployed successfully django app. But got 403 error while accessing static files.. I know it is permission related issue. So I tried all the ways. but nothing is workout.

gave 777 permission and www-data user. still I got permission denied error.

[file path structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/it9jY.png)

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(CORE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = "static/"

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(CORE_DIR, 'core/static'),
)
```

```
location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/FunQuiz-backend/FunQuizAPI/staticfiles/;
        autoindex on;
    }
```

**Important: when I give wrong path in static location.. still I got 403 permission denied error**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `root` to `alias`

```
location /static/ {
    alias /home/ubuntu/FunQuiz-backend/FunQuizAPI/staticfiles/;
    autoindex on;
}
```

Change user to `root` or `ubuntu` in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
user    ubuntu;  ## or root if ubuntu also gives permission denied error
```

Restart `nginx` for changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It's working. pls explain why you suggest to change user to ubuntu instead of www-data in nginx.conf file.

Comment: There might be no www-data user in your system. Check via `users` command in ubuntu.